# One arm of mesh disfigures when posing

Tags: mesh, rigging

I have a rigged model with one arm that distorts and disfigures when posing while the opposite doesn't.  The disfiguring arm doesn't have any modifiers or settings (As far as I've been able to find) that are any different from the arm that poses correctly and neither do the bones.  The only thing I can figure is that maybe it has something to do with it being a duplicated + mirrored version of the side that works correctly, although the normals have all been recalculated and the mesh origins are correct.

I'm really at a complete loss here.

Here's a gif of whats happening: [image]

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your [bone roll](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/armatures/bones/editing/transform.html#armature-bone-roll) is the same (or mirrored) on both arms?

Comment: This actually did make it a little bit better as a few of the bone rolls were off and the envelope on the Hand_IK.R was different than the Hand_IK.L (Although this didn't seem to change anything)

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed doubles before you rigged the mesh?

Before ever rigging, you should always as a rule remove doubles in your mesh. 
Anymore when you finished modelling, select your entire mesh, press hotkey W and select "Remove Doubles." That way, you will have leas tearing of topology and less disfigurements too.

[image: Remove Doubles]

Comment: I've tried that, yea.  I first removed doubles and then recalculated normals for each mesh.  Do you think combining each mesh into a single mesh would fix the issue? I'm not sure how that would affect my weight painting (if at all), but I wouldn't think that having multiple meshes would be the issue because the model is made up of 10 and the right arm is the only one causing issues.

Comment: I think I know your problem. I just remembered something from one of FB Blender groups: limp topology. When you bend a limb or finger, there has to be less topology on the closing side.  I think you will want to see this one link immediately below and check out the others too. 
http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Limb_Topology 

https://pin.it/lqw5eoi7jlyb7m 
https://pin.it/s6dx2237cbe4ym 
https://pin.it/bknsngtbclat3k

Comment: If the limb topology rules interest you, then you will want to check out that guy in Facebook. His previous post got me interested me in limb topology and his name is Sage Light Bwk, one of the best, biggest brains in Blender communities. He is the Admin of Blender NPR & Stylised Rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Alright guys, turns out the weight painting was just off.  The bone rolls were also off on the messed up arm and fixing them in edit mode made it a bit better, so I figured that now re-parenting that arm to the armature with automatic weights would add weights just like the opposite arm but it doesn't.

For some reason, the automatic weight painting isn't working right on this arm so I'll have to do it manually, I guess. Idk why it would paint the weights differently on that arm.

Thanks